# Overriding width of span and b elements

Tags: html, css, width, overriding

I have a bolded text block where I'd like to control the size of. Unfortunately, it appears to be resisting every effort to constrain its (actual) size. My goal is to have it to do ellipsis on text overflow but that's not happening because it just extends off-screen. It does get properly cut off by the boundary of the parent but that doesn't look elegant.

I have searched online for a solution but I don't see anything useful due to the immense amount of noise associated with the keywords I use (i.e. span, override width, b element, etc). I have made a sample code below to illustrate my problem (where span and b elements resist width overrides)

```
<body>
<b class="token_actor_cell" title="(AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA) AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA" style="
    /* width: 100px; */
    padding: 1px;
    margin: 1px;
    color: brown;
    max-width: 100px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
">(AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA) AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA</b>
<span class="token_actor_cell" title="(AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA) AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA" style="
    /* width: 100px; */
    padding: 1px;
    margin: 1px;
    color: blue;
    max-width: 100px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
">(AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA) AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA</span>
<p class="token_actor_cell" title="(AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA) AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA" style="
    /* width: 100px; */
    padding: 1px;
    margin: 1px;
    color: green;
    max-width: 100px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
">(AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA) AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA</p>
</body>
```

I suppose I can change my element type to p but I kinda prefer to stick with my original element type if possible.

Input on this would be appreciated. I am pretty sure it is a well-understood issue.

Comment: just add display:block; to span and b tags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should play around with the "display" property.
If you want it to behave like a `<p>` Tag you should use `display: block;`. If you want to keep the inline behaviour of your elements you should use `display: inline-block;`. Then they will listen to your width.

Answer (score 0):

By default inline elements (like span and b) don't have width. To make them adjust to a width you need them to float either left or right. This will create a block box around them.

You example with float left http://jsfiddle.net/0ja257L9/

```
.token_actor_cell{
    float: left;
}
```

Or you can use display: inline-block for the inline elements :)

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
<b class="token_actor_cell" title="(AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA) AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA" style="
width: 100px; 
padding: 1px;
margin: 1px;
color: brown;
display:block;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
overflow:hidden"> 
(AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA) AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
</b>
```

Seems to work for me.